# what's new not updating on google play store

Tags: android, google-play

So google has changed their publishing interface so that `Recent changes` no longer goes under `Store Listing` but under a specific apk. The problem is, I don't see where to add those comments in the apk that is actually in production. For the unpublished APKs I can just go in "Show details". Does anyone know how to add those comments for the APK that is actually serving in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to https://play.google.com/apps/publish
2. Click on your application
3. Click on `APK` in the left menu
4. Click on the version you have in production
5. Scroll down to `What's new in this version?`
6. Click on the seemingly-uneditable text. It should become editable.
7. Save

Comment: I have had the same issue a few days ago - the new interface is rather confusing at first.